# Prove continuity of a function that is defined through a geometric construction

Tags: geometry, functions, continuity

I need to prove that a function is continuous, but it is not defined explicitly,it's like this: given a point $P$ on a circumference and an angle $0\le a\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ defined by $P$ and another point on the circumference, say $P'$, draw tangent lines through both points and the point of intersection is $f(P)$.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You can fix one of those two points, say $P'$, and also fix the angle $a$. Then, your function is a function of $P$. Now, given $P'$, $a$, and the radius $r$ (also fixed) of the circumference, you can find the explicit analytical form of $f(P)$ and then prove its continuity.

Comment: This question makes sense only if the point $P'$ is fixed and the point $P$ is the parameter to the function. Is that the case?

Comment: yeah, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for a proof. Let C be the unit circle centered at the origin of the $(x,y)$-plane. Let $P^{\prime} = (1,0)$.

Now the tangent line at $P^{\prime}$ is the vertical line $x = 1$.

Let $f(x,y) : C \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the function you have described.

This function may be written componentwise as

\begin{align}
f(x,y) = (g(x,y), h(x,y)).
\end{align}

The x-coordinate of the intersection point is always $1$, so $g(x,y) = 1$ identically on $C$.

The function $h(x,y)$ is essentially a skewed projection onto the line $x = 1$. You should need only algebra and trigonometry to find out exactly what the $y$ coordinate of the intersection point is. It should just be a linear combination of trigonometric functions, which is continuous.

After this, you will know each component of $f$ is continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.

Finally, show that you can scale and rotate the circle without breaking the continuity.

Comment: but what are g and h?

Comment: $g$ is the $x$-coordinate of the intersection point; $h$ is the $y$-coordinate of the intersection point.

Comment: alright, thanks